# GCC/G++ Dockerfile builds locally; fails in Hub

Tags: c++, gcc, dockerhub

I recently submitted this Dockerfile to the [Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jeyoor/avida/~/dockerfile/)

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Jeyan Oorjitham <jeyoor@gmx.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   build-essential \
   cmake \
   git \
   libncurses-dev
RUN git clone https://github.com/devosoft/avida.git
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c",  "cd avida; ./build_avida"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

It is intended to build [Avida](http://avida.devosoft.org) from source.

The build succeeds locally, but I receive the following error from the Docker Hub.

```
[91mc++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
[0m
[91mPlease submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
...
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/apto-test
...
Built target apto-test
[91mmake[1]: *** [avida-core/CMakeFiles/avida-core.dir/all] Error 2
[0m
[91mmake: [0m
[91m*** [all] Error 2
```

[Full output](https://hub.docker.com/r/jeyoor/avida/builds/b6gq6ruftsclbnpejdooh7s/)

The build seems to be failing around the time it tries to link together the test executable for [Apto](http://programerror.com/software/apto/).

Some Googling led me to [this thread](https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Installing-NuPIC-on-Ubuntu) which seems to point to a lack of memory when linking large binaries...

Could memory be the problem or am I missing something else? Is there any way for me to increase the memory allocated to the Docker Hub build?

Comment: It sounds like your link points to the problem: Apto needs C++11, and stupid C++11 needs 2++GB to run (?!?).  You should be able to specify [--memory](https://gist.github.com/afolarin/15d12a476e40c173bf5f) in your docker-run command.

Comment: @paulsm4 What do you mean C++11 takes 2 GB to run?

Comment: Looks like Docker Hub's recent upgrade has caused a [few urgent issues](https://forums.docker.com/t/known-issues-new-docker-hub/2851)... I might cross-post this question to the Docker support forum in a few days after the post-upgrade intensity has died down.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: No resolution...

here's the cross post to Docker Forums...

https://forums.docker.com/t/gcc-g-dockerfile-builds-locally-fails-in-hub/2958